# How does one get sbt-idea to work in scala-2.10 project?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-idea

I had a lot of trouble getting [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) to work in my Scala 2.10 project.

I tried compiling `sbt-idea` from its git repo, making sure that to have set

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-RC5"
```

in `build/Build.scala`, and using `publish-local` command to compile it in git. But I nevertheless keep getting

```
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
```

when I then use that in my published version, say by simply adding

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

to the `project/plugins.sbt` file.

Answer (score 7):

Don't think you need to build SBT for Scala 2.10. I keep my gen-idea and eclipse project generators in the global build.sbt file and it works for all my projects (or so it seems ;-)

I'm using Ubuntu, so where the SBT config files are saved on your computer may be different.

Create a folder called `plugins` under the hidden sbt directory. On Linux this is located at `~/.sbt` (where tilde is an alias for your home directory). So now you should have `~/.sbt/plugins`

Then create a file called `build.sbt` under this directory and add the following to it:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Sonatype releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

To test, I just generated a scala 2.10 project with it, and it seems fine.

Oh, the file above also adds support for the `eclipse` command in SBT if you want to generate Scala-IDE projects.

Comment: thanks. That in fact helped a lot. I also had another problem that was getting in the way, making it doubly difficult to fix this.

Comment: Pleasure @HenryStory, sorry for not helping on getting gen-idea itself running on 2.10, but as you noticed, it does not seem to be a pre-requisite.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use an older version of `gen-idea` by adding the following to `project/plugins.sbt` in the project itself:

```
import sbt._

import Defaults._

libraryDependencies += sbtPluginExtra(
    m = "com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0", // Plugin module name and version
    sbtV = "0.12",    // SBT version
    scalaV = "2.9.2"    // Scala version compiled the plugin
)
```